# Joining two strings together in NASM

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I looked all over google for ways to do this, I found some but I really found them to be overly complex for what I need. For starters, I need this to be done through a loop, the place where I'm putting my strings is also initially empty, so I'm sure that is bound to create some issues.

Anyway this is my code:

```
%include "io.mac"

.DATA
    filename_msg db 'Enter the file name: ', 0
    number_prompt_msg db 'Enter the number of bases: ',0 ;asks for the number of bases to be used 
    finish_msg db 'Operation completed, DNA file generated',0 ;tells the user when the file is complete
    error_msg db 'Operation failed, please try again', 10
    base_A db 'A',0
    base_C db 'C',0
    base_G db 'G',0 
    base_T db 'T',0
    base_length equ $ - base_A
;----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
.UDATA
    number_of_bases rest 1 ;defined by the user 
    random_number resb 1   
    filename: resd 20       ;defined by the user
    base rest 1
    file_descriptor resd 1    ;used to generate the file
    characters_to_write rest 1
;-------------------------------------------------------------------
;start of code, and message prompts for the user
.CODE 

    .STARTUP

;asks user for filename 
ask_details:
    PutStr filename_msg
    GetStr filename, 300

    ;asks user for the number of bases
    PutStr number_prompt_msg 
    GetLInt [number_of_bases]

;------------------------------------------------------------
;file creation 
    mov EAX, 8  ;creates the file
    mov EBX, filename
    mov ECX, 644O   ;octal instruction 
    int 80h     ;kernel interrupt
    cmp EAX,0   ;throws error if something is amiss
    jbe error 
    mov [file_descriptor],EAX
    mov ECX,[number_of_bases]
;-------------------------------------------------------------
;randomization of base numbers 
writing_loop:
    rdtsc 
    mov EAX, EDX
    mov EDX, 0
    div ECX
    mov EDX, 0
    mov EBX, 4
    div EBX 
    mov [random_number], EDX
    mov EDX, 0
    mov EAX,[random_number]
    cmp EAX,0
    je assignment_A
    cmp EAX,1
    je assignment_C
    cmp EAX,2
    je assignment_G
    cmp EAX,3
    je assignment_T
join_char:
    mov [base + EBX],EBX
    loop writing_loop 
    PutStr base
    .EXIT
;------------------------------------------------------------
;file generation error message 
error:
    PutStr error_msg
    jmp ask_details
;------------------------------------------------------------
;assignments 
assignment_A:
    mov EBX, [base_A]
    jmp join_char

assignment_C:
    mov EBX, [base_C]
    jmp join_char

assignment_T:
    mov EBX, [base_T]
    jmp join_char

assignment_G:
    mov EBX, [base_G]
    jmp join_char
```

First it compares some random numbers I obtained with rdtsc, depending on what comes up, it will assign a letter to EBX this letter(base_A,base_C,base_T or base_G) is then supposed to go into `base`. I tried using 
`mov [base + EBX],EBX` but that just printed an empty space, I used this because it seemed to work in the examples I looked at, but I'm not really sure how concatenating works in NASM. I don't know if anyone knows any simple methods to concatenate those characters together, if it is possible. This is really minor, so I'm hoping I don't have to add a lot of code, the only thing I need this string for is to write it in a file later. I would do that without the string but I need all my registers to write to the file so I can't do it letter by letter.

EDIT: What I need to know how to do is how to join each letter once it has been picked. Base is empty for example, then after a letter is picked, it gets thrown in there, however after the loop runs again, another letter will be picked, and I need to add it to base after all that's done.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but I see some problems. `random_number` is too small (one byte) to hold `EDX` (32 bits, 4 bytes, one dword). This is going to scribble on the first three bytes of `base`. Use `resd 1` or just put `dl` in it. You appear to be doing `div ECX` - and `loop`ing - with no known value in `ECX`. `rdtsc` returns `EDX:EAX` - `EDX` dosen't change often, so you're probably getting the same "random" number each time. In any case, one of your 4 `je`s is going to be true. After your "assignments", you jump back to `join_char`, so `mov [base + EBX], EBX` isn't executed

Comment: The registersize of the EBX register is 4 byte, but this line for example reserved only 2 bytes: `base_A db 'A',0`.

Comment: This isn't the complete code, I didn't want to put it all, because last time I did I got in trouble, anyway. Let me just put everything then. Sorry if this has some stuff that doesn't make sense, I've had to find out how to do all this on my own since my professor didn't teach it to me.